# Hello there. I am using react-slick for carousel. React-slick sets centerMode true for every carousel

Tags: reactjs, next.js, carousel, react-slick

I am using react-slick for carousel. React-slick using centerMode true for every carousel even I don't use this attribute. How can I turn off this attribute. centerMode= false is not working [this is setting for react-slick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOj0v.png) [This is Slider component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tA3Am.png)

I try this: centerMode = false but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

From the API reference: [centerMode: false](https://react-slick.neostack.com/docs/api/#centerMode) by default, which means the same result if write `centerMode: false`. It'd be great to debug if you provided any snippets. However, here is the working example: [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-kepler-qwiksf?file=/src/App.tsx).

Besides, please have a look at the link below to see the issue & solution visually: [TestWise Replay | StackOverFlow QA - React-slick centerMode](https://dashboard.testwise.io/replays/AIabcoXKnip)